# Oop's Not Found" error in conjunction with Google Sign-in and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, single-sign-on, google-signin

I have setup [google Login plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-login/) in Jenkins and enabled SSO. Configured Authorized redirect like this ex: https://abc.io/securityRealm/finishLogin. I am able to do login and logout, but if i hit login from the logout page, seeing below error

`Oops! Not Found This page may not exist, or you may not have permission to see it.`
though, i can see my username on this page(means signed in, if i click on Homepage/Dashboard able to view the page).
`https://abc.io/securityRealm/` is the URL i see on that problematic page. I am a beginner with this plugin, so not sure if i missed anything while configuring. Could some one help me on this. Thanks!

I tried with multiple OAuth creds to see if it's a specific OAuth creds issue, but no luck, it is happening with every OAuth creds set i have.

I tried with multiple OAuth creds to see if it's a specific OAuth creds issue, but no luck.